# Form submit button gives all data values in while loop

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a while loop in PHP(custom).It is fetching all data(Posts) from a wordpress site ok. But there is a problem with form (Submit Button).Actually i want to generate a link from selected doamin such as xyz.com and abc.com. when select domain and click on the submit button.it creates the link of the post such as xyz.com/wordpress/?p=10 . zee.com/wordpress/?p=11 zee.com/wordpress/?p=12
keep in mind it creates all post link.i want to do it with only one post.so please help me in this case .
This is my code.

```
   <?php

   $sql = "select * from wp_tableposts where post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' Order by ID DESC;";
   $res = mysql_query($sql);
   while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
     $a = $data['guid'];//**** guid is  link of posts
     $urlparts = parse_url($a);
     //**** This is removing the  domain name of wordpress posts
     $extracted = $urlparts['path'].'?'.$urlparts['query'] ;

     //for example:www.wordpress.com/?p=10
     //it gives: /?p=10

       if  (isset($data['guid']))
           {echo $extracted; }
     //**** This is removing the  domain name of wordpress posts

          echo'ID:'.$data['ID'].'';// it is id of wordpress post    
          echo'Post Contant:'.$data['post_content'].'';//*** it is contant of wordpress post
          echo'Post Title:'.    $data['post_title'].'';//*** it is title of wordpress post
          echo'Link:'.  $extracted.'';//*** this is the removed link of post    
     ?>


      <form method="GET">
           <select  name="subject">
           <?php
           //**** this is getting domains (xyz.com, abc.com)from another table
             $sql1 = "select * from wp_domains ;";
             $res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
             while ($data1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
              {
                echo'
                  <option value="'. $data1['bb_domains'].'">'.$data1['bb_domains'].'</option>
      ';
              }
            ?>     
            </select>
               <input type="text" value="<?php echo  $_GET['subject'] ;?><?php echo  $extracted;?>" name="">
                    <input type="submit" name ="submit" >
                  </form>
             <?php

                      }

                     ?>
```

Comment: So you want to add p=number to the value of the option?

Comment: 1st.awesomz.com check this site.i am trying to make when click on generate button it makes the link.only one post .but my  code generate all  all post link .this is only the problem